# Filter by array of values on Excel

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a question about filtering rows in Excel.

I have a large table, with over 10 000 rows. Each row has a unique `ID`.
I duplicated my table and made modifications on some rows and highlighted them.

The thing I need to select rows based on an array of values of unique `ID`.
(the `ID` field is like this: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5,.., 10500`) form an unmodified copy of the first Excel table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be demonstrating with the following sample data.

[image: Sample Tables for Filtering]

The predominantly blue table in A1:D16 is a ListObject named *myTable*. The predominantly green table in F3:I13 is a ListObject named *MyTable_Copy*.

To filter the *myTable* ListObject based on the *ID*'s found in the *ID* column of *myTable_Copy*, we need to construct an array of the ID numbers as strings. A function can be used for that. Remember that the filter will be expecting an array of strings that look like integers, not true integers. If you have special number formatting like leading zeroes, the function will have to be changed to accommodate that.

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to Insert ► Module (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the following into the new module code sheet named something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*.

```
Function gather_IDs(sTBL As String, sCOL As String)
    Dim aIDs() As String, i As Long, id As Range
    For Each id In Range(sTBL & "[" & sCOL & "]")
        ReDim Preserve aIDs(0 To i)
        aIDs(i) = CStr(id.Value2)
        i = i + 1
    Next id
    gather_IDs = aIDs
End Function
```

Now we need a sub to call that function and filter *myTable* based on the returned array. In the same module sheet, paste the following.

```
Sub main()
    Dim vIDs As Variant

    vIDs = gather_IDs("myTable_Copy", "ID")

    With ActiveSheet
        .ListObjects("myTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=(vIDs), _
            Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With

End Sub
```

Note that the variant array passed into the `Criteria1` parameter is wrapped in brackets. **The brackets are important.** Without them, the `.AutoFilter` command does not recognize the variant array as an array and will only use the first value in the array as filter criteria.

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to open the **Macros** dialog and *Run* the **main** macro. You should receive results similar to the following.

[image: Tables Filtered by Array]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want to be able to easily see/access the modified rows?

You could add a separate column, add a value at the modified rows and then sort the entire table by this column. You'd find your modified entries at top or bottom of the table.

As soon as you don't need the information any more, clear this new column and resort the table by the ID (if necessary). Variant: leave this column and increment the value you insert when editing, so you can sort by

Comment: I need to use the array of values for selecting the rows from a copy of my document. I will modify the question.